# How to increase jquery variable size limit

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, xml

the string which gets data from the web service

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਜਗਰੂਪ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਪ੍ਰਿਥਾ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਸਾਧੂ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"80/913"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਗੁਰਮੀਤ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਮਹਿੰਦਰ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਸਾਧੂ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"57/1826"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਗੁਰਦੀਪ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਮਹਿੰਦਰ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਸਾਧੂ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"57/1826"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਰਾਜਿੰਦਰ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਪ੍ਰਿਥਾ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਸਾਧੂ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"491/913"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਅਮਰਜੀਤ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਨਿਰਭੈ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"16/913"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਸ਼ਿੰਦਰ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਸੱਜਨ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"4/83"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਸਵਰਨ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਨਿਰਭੈ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"16/913"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਬਲਵੰਤ ਕੌਰ ਵਿਧਵਾ ਨਿਰਭੈ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"1/83"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਦਲਜੀਤ ਕੌਰ ਵਿਧਵਾ ਬਲਦੇਵ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"17/913"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਗੁਰਵਿੰਦਰ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਬਲਦੇਵ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"53/1826"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਅਸ਼ੋਕ ਕੁਮਾਰ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਪ੍ਰੇਮ ਕੁਮਾਰ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਬਿਹਾਰੀ ਲਾਲ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"57/913"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਅਜੈਬ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਸੱਜਨ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"19/1826"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਸੁਰਜੀਤ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਭਰਪੂਰ ਸਿੰਘ ਉਰਫ ਕਾਕੂ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"2/83"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਸਰਬਜੀਤ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਭਰਪੂਰ ਸਿੰਘ ਉਰਫ ਕਾਕੂ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"2/83"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਗੁਰਨੈਬ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਸੱਜਨ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"4/83"}]</string>
```

here is my jquery code to fetch the XML data from the web service

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        
        var vill = "FE438A26-F985-DC11-BAB5-000E0CA4A31A";
        var teh = "164";
        var khr = "243//4";

        

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://__link____/giswebservice/GisWebService.asmx/GisWebService',
            data: { village_id: vill, tehsil_id: teh, khasra_no: khr },
            method: 'post',
            datatype: 'xml',
            success: function (data) {
                
                var str;                    
                str = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(data);                
                alert(str);

               
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

but the alert not shows the whole output, in the end, it shows ....(dash), some record is missing,  and the output is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">[{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਜਗਰੂਪ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਪ੍ਰਿਥਾ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ  ਸਾਧੂ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"80/913"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":" ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ  ਸਾਧੂ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"57/1826"},{"khewat_no":"54","Column1":"ਗੁਰਦੀਪ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਮਹਿੰਦਰ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ  ਸਾਧੂ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"57/1826"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":" ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਪ੍ਰਿਥਾ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ  ਸਾਧੂ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"491/913"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":" ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਨਿਰਭੈ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ  ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"16/913"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ  ਸੱਜਨ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"4/83"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਸਵਰਨ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਨਿਰਭੈ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ  ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"16/913"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਬਲਵੰਤ ਕੌਰ ਵਿਧਵਾ ਨਿਰਭੈ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ  ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"1/83"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਦਲਜੀਤ ਕੌਰ ਵਿਧਵਾ ਬਲਦੇਵ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ  ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"17/913"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਗੁਰਵਿੰਦਰ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਬਲਦੇਵ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ  ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"53/1826"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਅਸ਼ੋਕ ਕੁਮਾਰ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਪ੍ਰੇਮ ਕੁਮਾਰ ਪੁੱਤਰ  ਬਿਹਾਰੀ ਲਾਲ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"57/913"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਅਜੈਬ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ  ਸੱਜਨ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"19/1826"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਸੁਰਜੀਤ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਭਰਪੂਰ ਸਿੰਘ ਉਰਫ ਕਾਕੂ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ  ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"2/83"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਸਰਬਜੀਤ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਭਰਪੂਰ ਸਿੰਘ ਉਰਫ ਕਾਕੂ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ  ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ vbcrlf ","owner_share":"2/83"},{"khewat_no":"34","Column1":"ਗੁਰਨੈਬ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ ਕਰਤਾਰ ਸਿੰਘ ਪੁੱਤਰ  ਸੱਜਨ ਸਿੰਘ ...
```

so how to increase the variable size so that the full record is shown in alert

Comment: `alert()` is not the best idea for displaying lots of data. What does `console.log(str)` show?

Comment: yes, sir, I know the alert is not the best idea for displaying lots of data, I only test that the variable contains whole data or not but it shows some missing record, so what another method to store the whole fetching data in a variable.